# Force file download with Resume support ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

i know how to force download a file with server side code. here is sample code

```
Response.Clear(); //eliminates issues where some response has already been sent
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.sql", filename));
Response.Write(yourSQL);
Response.End();
```

i like to know what header info i need to add to give resume support as a result client can resume download if paused. i got a link but it has answer with many line of code

**http://forums.asp.net/t/1218116.aspx?Resume+Download+for+Huge+Files

[how resume able file download in asp.net with c# -> best way (for large files too)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948316/how-resume-able-file-download-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp-best-way-for-large-fil)

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Implement-resume-in-aspnet-c1bbde36**

thanks

Comment: I think this is what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15610694/193634